# Set textbox text without removing binding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have something like:

```
<TextBox Text={Binding MyDate, 
               ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True, 
               ValidatesOnDataErrors=True} />
```

**I have a checkbox than when checked need to make the textbox readonly and display "N/A"**. Validations are already created for `MyDate` and if a validation error triggers it will display an error message on the textbox. If I bind that textbox to a different property of type string then I will have to create validations for that string. **How can I keep the textbox binded to MyDate and display N/A?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have two textboxes. One binded and one readonly with "N/A". Make visible/invisible each textboxes by IsChecked value of the checkbox.